# Find files then move them and rename them at the same time?

Tags: find, rename, gzip, move, amazon-s3

Currently I use three steps to `gzip` some static assets and then use `s3cmd` to an S3 bucket (technically it's a Digital Ocean Spaces bucket). Here's what I do:

1. `$ find . -type f -name '*.css' | xargs -I{} gzip -k -9 {}`
2. `$ find . -type f -name '*.css.gz' | xargs -I{} s3cmd put --acl-public --add-header='Content-Encoding: gzip' {} s3://mybucket/assets/{}`
3. But then I have to manually change all of the extensions in my bucket to remove the `.gz` extension.

Is there a way that I won't have to manually do step 3? I'd love to know if it's possible in step 2 to remove the `.gz` extension in the destination. I do want to keep the original files on my server though, so that's a deal breaker.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan that makes no sense

Comment: It just means that the two reviewers who rejected your edit suggestion over-ruled my approval vote but in this case they were wrong. I just thought I'd say that the review system mostly works (just not in this case) and to not let this instance discourage you from making future edit suggestions.

Comment: I understand what happened, still it makes no sense ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-exec` action in `find` so that you can do shell string manipulation on the filename. The parameter expansion `"${var%.*}"` can be used to remove the extension. Below is an example.

`find . -type f -name '*.css.gz' -exec bash -c 's3cmd put --acl-public --add-header="Content-Encoding: gzip" "$1" "s3://mybucket/assets/${1%.*}"' -- {} \;`